# Add different cooldown for different users for python bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, disnake

I use disnake library in python.
I have list of premium users in bot and I want they to have a shorter cooldown for commands, than regular users. For example regular users have cooldown of 10 s, and premium users have cooldown of 3 s

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands


pro_users = [1234567890, 907508957384]
intents = disnake.Intents.all()
client = commands.InteractionBot(intents=intents)


@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
@client.slash_command()
async def super_command(inter):
    await inter.channel.send('Hello')


client.run('TOKEN')
```

I had an idea to raise CooldownError in command's body, but I want to know if I can do it without raising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do this by having your own cooldown method. By having some kind of data structure that tracks when a user last used the command you can have different cooldowns for different users.

```
import datetime

pro_users = [1234567890, 907508957384]
SUPER_COOLDOWNS = {}
NORMAL_TIMEOUT = 60 # in seconds
PRO_TIMEOUT = 30 # in seconds

intents = disnake.Intents.all()
client = commands.InteractionBot(intents=intents)


@client.slash_command()
async def super_command(inter):
    user_id = inter.author.id
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    if prev_time := SUPER_COOLDOWNS.get(user_id):
        timeout = PRO_TIMEOUT if user_id in pro_users else NORMAL_TIMEOUT
        if (now - prev_time).total_seconds() < timeout:
            message = f"You used this command too recently. Please wait `{timeout}` seconds."
            await inter.send(message, ephemeral=True)

    # set the time they last used the command to now
    SUPER_COOLDOWNS[user_id] = now
    await inter.channel.send('Hello')
```

You can expand the SUPER_COOLDOWNS dict as needed, etc. But hopefully you get the gist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's really a good solution.  I modified the code a little and now it works as I need

Comment: Glad to have helped! If you could - please mark the answer as the solution :)